# Share data between React components with no relation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm working on a React component library that allows for client-side data filtering by passing an array of objects and an `<input/>` as props to a `<SearchFilter/>` component. I want to return the filtered results to a *separate* `<SearchResults/>` component that can be rendered elsewhere in the tree (i.e. the results component doesn't have to be a child of the input component).

I've got the filtering figured out, but I'm not sure the best route to take in React on getting the filtered data to the `<SearchResults/>` component.

This is what I'd like to end up with...

```
<SearchFilter
  data={data}
  input={<input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>}
/>
```

Then, using Render Props to return the data and map over that to return JSX, there would be the results component. Something like this...

```
<SearchResults 
  render={data => (
    data.map(el => (
      <div>
       <span>{data.someProperty}</span>
      </div>
    )
  )}
/>
```

This is what I'd like to achieve because I want to allow for rendering the `<SearchFilter/>` component at one place in the tree, and allow the `<SearchResults/>` component to be rendered *elsewhere*, so that there's maximum flexibility in how the tree is composed and, therefore, how the view is rendered.

I've looked into the Context API, but it seems like that would require a handful more components to be a part of my library, which further complicates what I'm trying to achieve. If that's the only way around it, then that's fine, but I wanted to ask and see if anyone can think of another solution.

Thanks!

Comment: A state management system of some sort is unavoidable. Don't think of Redux as an overengineered solution, if that's how you currently feel. Redux has a ton of boilerplate, but the control you have over data flow throughout your web app is completely worth it. I honestly can't even imagine making a React app without Redux

Answer (score 2):

The bigger issue is that you will need to manage a state that is shared between components on a higher level, i.e., any component that will wrap these other two components, ultimately. With plain React, this state would be managed by the parent (or ancestor) component, passing down the relevant values as props. This opposed to the, usually bad, idea to have sibling components influence each other's state, since you well get into the "who's boss here"-problem.

The thing the Context API handles is not having to pass down props for things that typically don't change (or: typically shouldn't cause renders to trigger often).

A global state store, such as Redux, can help you modelling this, but in essence it's not much more than 'a' component managing state, and other components rendering according to that state. Events within the lower components trigger changes in the data, which will cause the state to change, which will cause the props of the children to change, which then will cause re-renders.

I'd advise you to try using this simple pattern:

```
class Search ... {
    state = {data: [], text: ""}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchFilter 
                    data={this.state.data} 
                    onSearch={() => this.fetchNewData()} 
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.targetElement.value})}
                    text={this.state.text} 
                />
                <SearchResults data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    fetchNewData() {
        fetch('/url?text=' + this.state.text)
            .then((newData) => { this.setState({data: newData}); })
    }
}
```

Something along these lines. If you have trouble modelling stuff like this, you can use Redux to force you to do it in a similar way, and avoid managing local state intermixing with global state (which is typically something that is hard to manage).

If you do this right, components that have no state (i.e., aren't responsible for managing state and thus have no event handlers) can all become pure components, i.e. stateless components, i.e. functions that return JSX based on props:

```
const SearchResults = ({data}) => <div>{data.map( () => <etc /> )}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, this isn't really what I'm trying to do. What I'm after is providing a means for filtering data that's _already_ in application state, not fetching data and setting it to application state based on a search query. So, ultimately, I won't be mutating or changing the data in anyway, just rendering a subset of the data based on user input. Maybe the whole thing is a bad idea, but yeah.

Comment: @joehdodd You're definitely changing data. Filtered data differs from original data. If there's already `data` in state then `filteredData` should be additionally set, which can be `[...data]` by default.

Comment: @estus Okay. I guess what I meant was that I'm not _mutating_ the data at the data at the source. /shrug

Comment: @joehdodd At this point it doesn't matter if `filteredData` is totally new data or a subset of existing data that was obtained from `this.state.data.filter(...)` You have problems with original code because it doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and it's unclear how these components are used and how the state (`data`) is managed. It's hard for answers to be better than the question is.

Comment: @estus. Okay. My apologies for a poorly worded and poorly conceived question. It’s a sincere question, but I guess that’s not what counts. I tried to provide what was important and the problem to be solved. I _thought_ my problem wasn’t about how data is managed, so I asked what might be available to me that would enable my components to ingest some user input and  application data in one place, and returned filtered data based on that user input elsewhere. Apologies. I’ll do better next time so that my question is deemed worthy of the time it takes for someone to answer it.

Comment: @joehdodd No, this is all about data. That's why state management libs like Redux exist. React context API serves a similar purpose and could possibly be used here. Less attractive option is to pass `data` and `setData` handler deeply via props.

Comment: @estus Got it. I’ve ultimately decided to leave the user input implementation up to users of the component. Now all it does is take in an input value and some data and return the filtered data back via a callback. From there, it’s another implementation decision left up to the developer. Basically all it does now is wrap my filter logic.

Comment: @joehdodd That's ikely the right solution if you intend it to be used by other devs, otherwise they would be tied to your state implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data store class that holds your filter, pass it in as a property to both components, and have your SearchFilter component change a value in that.