# How to pass data between two unrelated components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

Heyy guys, how can I pass data from one component (let A) to another component (let B) in React ? i.e, suppose I have two different components A and B, B is not a child component of A and also both A and B doesn't have a common parent...so how can I pass the data from component A to component B then?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, that is a good question you have but first please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and secondly here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173330/share-data-between-react-components-with-no-relation) to your question existing in our site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share data between React components with no relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173330/share-data-between-react-components-with-no-relation)

Comment: in short, the best way is through a service which sits at the root/app level. You will need to read more into that as it is a suggestion, or you can use redux to create a data store which can be accessed from any component's context

Comment: As an aside, I am of the opinion that React's built in `context` API is the way to go, and Redux has largely been rendered redundant by it.  https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context API in React for passing data between unrelated components.