# React - Pass data in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-router-dom, react-props

So, I'm having a hard time passing data between two unrelated components. I have this code below, but I don't know how to receive it from the other component

```
<Button
   className='search__button'
   variant="contained"
   color="primary"
   size="large"
   component={Link}
   to={{
     pathname: "/home",
     state: { data: results }
   }}
>
```

I want to pass the variable "results" which is a Map of a string and an object Book (Map<string, Book>) to a component. Basically, my question is, how do I retrieve data in my Home component?

Thank you

Comment: store it on the global state. you can get idea form [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173629/8928037](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173629/8928037)

Comment: You can get it from location using a hook https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation you can also see an example of this in the auth example https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending state with route transitions you can access it on the `location` object of the receiving route in a few different ways:

1. In the case of functional components you can use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

   ```
    const { state } = useLocation();
    // access state.data
   ```
2. If the component is rendered by a `Route` on the `render`, `component`, or `children` prop then [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) will be passed to the component. `location` will be a prop. Or you can decorate the component with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) have have the route props of the closest matching `Route` passed as props.

   ```
    const { location: { state } } = this.props;
    // access state.data
   ```

   or

   ```
    const { location: { state } } = props;
    // access state.data
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I receive the data but not on the first try. When I press the button for the 2nd time, that's when I receive the data, where is there a delay ?

Comment: @PatrickYoussef Does clicking this button also trigger *some* asynchronous callback, i.e. does it trigger some data fetching or similar?

Comment: No, at first, I initialize "let results: Filters = {}" (Filters is an interface I created). Then clicking the button calls a function that changes the variable "results". And then as you can see, I have a button that sends "results" to /home